# How to find the repository tab in developer console of Sales force

Tags: salesforce

How to find the repository tab in developer console of Sales force, i am using salesforce summer 14 developer edition. Any helps please, i am a new bee to salesforce.

Answer (score 0):

"New **File menu option** lets you create resources and replaces the Repository tab from previous versions."

File > Open Resource

https://developer.salesforce.com/releases/release/Summer13/New+Developer+Console+Updates

Comment: Thanks for your help John. But i am still not cleared with my doubt.I read in some tutorials that, the usage of Repository tab is to look around for the different objects and attributes used in a particular Apex class. So how can i check that in the new versions then?

Comment: "The Object Inspector provides a read-only reference for the fields of a standard or custom object, and their data types. To open the Object Inspector, click File | Open and select the object you want to view."  https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=code_dev_console_view_quick_schema.htm&language=en_US